# How to use "if contains"?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make a scheduler for work and I have a dropdown list of the hours that the employees work in one column and I want it to display how many hours it is next to that. I.e.:

```
Column B (Selected from a drop down menu)   Column C  
6:00 - 14:30                                to display 8 as it is an 8 hour shift   
10:00 - 15:00                               to display 5 as it is an 5 hour shift
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: whoops i meant 5 hour shift

Comment: What do you want to do with shifts that are not whole hours? Also do any shifts wrap around midnight?

Comment: There are only 8 hour shifts or 5 hour shifts, 8 hours is technically 8.5 but theres a 30 min unpaid break. And no there are no shifts past midnight.

Answer (score 0):

So for the sake of clarity, I am going to develop this step by step, in several columns. These could be combined into one impenetrable formula, but that will not help you follow. You can do what I suggest here and then hide the columns with the calculation.
Suppose your time is in column A. You can do the following in the first row (mine assumes row 1, if you have headers, probably row 2) and then copy the formulas on down. In column B, I placed, `=search("-",A1)`, which tells where the - sign is. In column C, I find the first time as a string with `=left(A1,B1-2)`, which takes the first characters up to 2 before the dash. In column D I have `=mid(A1,B1+2,5)` which takes from 2 characters after the dash to the end (if it is only 4 characters long, it copies 4 not 5),and finally in column E we find the desired result, with `=HOUR(timevalue(D1)-timevalue(C1))`.
That does what you asked. If you wanted to add minutes you could use `=MINUTE(timevalue(D1)-timevalue(C1))`. Finally if a 22:00 - 6:00 graveyard shift existed, you would need to add logic for it.
You could also simplify the string calculation by in column B using the formula `=split(A1,"-")` and then putting `=HOUR(timevalue(C1)-timevalue(B1))`

And so if you really want a single formula, it could be `=hour(INDEX((split(A1,"-")),2)-INDEX((split(A1,"-")),1))`, which subtracts the first part from the second and converts to hours.

If in the course of time you want to handle the wrap around midnight, `=iferror(hour(INDEX((split(A1,"-")),2)-INDEX((split(A1,"-")),1)),24-hour(INDEX((split(A1,"-")),1)-INDEX((split(A1,"-")),2)))` should do the trick.

UPDATE: Sheets recognizes the times that resulted from the split as times. So if in B1 you place `=split(A1,"-")`, D1 can contain `=C1-B1` if you are willing to keep the minutes. It even gives the right answer for 22:00 - 2:00.

Answer (score 0):

Make a table with a column for the shifts (this could be the list used for the Validation, if you chose that method) and a column immediately to its right of the respective shift durations. I named that table `Larry`. Then in C2 (assuming your first dropdown is in B2):

```
  =ArrayFormula(vlookup(B1:B,Larry,2,0))
```